# Error in exporting models in gltf2.0 format

Tags: texturing, export, eevee-render-engine, error, gltf

I recently updated my blender from 2.79 to 2.8. I tried exporting a model that I was working on in blender 2.79 from 2.8. I re-applied all my texture materials in eevee renderer and tried exporting my model in the new gltf2.0 format so, that I can import it into unity game engine for my project. While exporting blender takes way too much time than usual and finally gives a long list of errors. the fbx format export also does not seem right as it does not have same texture values as seen in blender parts of model are way too glossy and some other parts seem to use my displacement map as base color. I have attached an image of the list of errors blender is showing. Any help would be highly appreciated.enter image description here

[image: errors in blender gltf2.0 export]

[image: applied textures in blenders eevee renderer]

Comment: Can you share the .blend file that is causing the problem? (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: After getting such an error, please go to the menu "Window -> Toggle System Console".  From there you should be able to copy the full text of the error.  The last few lines are the most important, but they are cut off in your screenshot.

Comment: You could also try a 2.81 experimental build of Blender.  There have been performance improvements for large textures exporting to glTF.

Comment: @emackey I tried exporting using blender 2.81 alpha it doesn't seems to work either.

Comment: @rjg I tried uploading the .blend file on the link you provided but it does not accept files that are larger than 30 mb. My file size is 253 mb approx.

Comment: At this point we need to see the text of the error, not just a screenshot.  Please look for Blender's "Window" menu at the top, click "Toggle System Console", and then copy all of the error text out of that console.  Then, edit your question above to paste in all of the error text.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The issue was solved on it's own. I presume that something was wrong with my system. Though now i'm facing another issue. I'll create new thread for that.